# probability of N hash digits colliding

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-1

What is the probability of the first N hash digits colliding? for example i made a [script](https://gist.github.com/kylelk/6598353/raw/580ffb32c04bdaa96b9e9c4d164a4b4939fe3adb/Move_file.py) that appends the first  5 digits of the file's sha1 hash to the name of the file.

So will the probability of a collision be 16^5=1048576? Am i properly calculating the probability of a collision.

Comment: In discrete probability any event occurs with probability at most 1. You can expect a collision of the first 5 digits of a SHA1 hash after roughly 1000 hashes because of the [birthday bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_bound).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) is the generic name for such questions. You have $n$ values, selected randomly and uniformly in a space of size $t$; the probability that at least two of these values are identical is roughly equal to $n^2/(2t)$. When $n$ becomes close to $\sqrt{t}$, then the probability raises sharply. In your case, with 5 hexadecimal digits, you have a space of size $t = 16^5$, so you can expect your first collision, on average, when you get about 1000 values or so.

An intuitive way to think about it is that $n$ values make about $n^2/2$ pairs, and, "somehow", each pair has probability $1/t$ of being a collision. (The pairs are not independent of each other, but the intuition still works in that case.)

Comment: But I am not selecting the items randomly, I am selecting the first five. I am not using the decimal number base I am using hexadecimal. Thanks your answer is easy to understand.

Comment: Ah but you are using SHA1 to compute the hash of the filename. SHA1 is very close to a random function, so we can consider the bottom 5 hexadecimal digits as randomly chosen from the set of all such strings.

Comment: @user pg1989 I am not computing the hash of the file name, i am computing the hash of the file contents, I included a link to my code.

Comment: @kylek, the answer is still correct, regardless of what data you are hashing to get the five digits.